# Rails update_attributes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller, update-attributes

In my Rails app, `update_attribute` seems not working. I'm trying to update a boolean field called `billed`. The same command works great for two other tables.

Output of `rails console`:

```
>> Expense.find(28).update_attributes(:billed => true)
=> false
>> Expense.find(28).billed
=> false
```

`expenses_controller.rb`:

```
# PUT /expenses/1
# PUT /expenses/1.json
def update
  @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @expense.update_attributes(params[:expense])
      format.html { redirect_to @expense, notice: 'Expense was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render json: @expense }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @expense.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Expenses has these validations:

```
  validates_presence_of :employee_id       # Declare a required field
  validates_presence_of :unitcost          # Declare a required field
  validates_presence_of :quantity          # Declare a required field
  validates_presence_of :exp_date          # Declare a required field
  validates_presence_of :category_id       # Declare a required field
  validates_presence_of :description       # Declare a required field
  validates_presence_of :markup            # Declare a required field
  validates :markup, :format => { :with => /^\d{3}$/}, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
  validates :unitcost, :format => { :with => /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/}, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
  validates_numericality_of :quantity, :only_integer => true, :message => "Can only be whole number."
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have validation on expense?

Comment: Yes - I'll add to the question.

Comment: Use `update_attribute` instead of `update_attributes` to update single column.

Comment: That worked - add an answer and I'll accept it - THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **`update_attribute`** instead of **`update_attributes`** to update single column.

From the **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute)**

> update_attribute
>
> Updates a single attribute and saves the record without going through
>   the normal validation procedure. This is especially useful for boolean
>   flags on existing records. The regular update_attribute method in Base
>   is replaced with this when the validations module is mixed in, which
>   it is by default

```
Expense.find(28).update_attribute(:billed => true)
```